# C++ Curl download only if res == 0?

Tags: c++, curl, error-handling, libcurl

I'm download files from a web server using this code, this is working and after some help on here I now get error codes returned. This is the code I'm using:

```
void downloadFile(const char* url, const char* fname) {
    CURL *curl;
    FILE *fp;
    CURLcode res;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl){
        fp = fopen(fname, "wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        cout << res;
        if (res != 0) {
            cout << curl_easy_strerror(res);
            return;
        }

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to is only create the local file if `res` is 0 otherwise show the error code and stop the application.

Up to now everything I've tried has resulted in a file being created and often it will contain the return information from the server.

How do I only create the final file if `res` = 0 and if not show the error message and quit the application. ?

Thanks

Comment: its not really clear, where you are stuck. Why not just `if (res==0) {/* open file */} else { /* show error message and quit */}` ?

Comment: If you don't want to create the file unless writing it was successful, you'll find that it's rather difficult to do that. Why don't you delete it on failure? (Side note: check that `fp` is non-null before attempting the download.)

Comment: Hi. If `res != 0` I still end up with a file created which contains the http server error output..  One option I have is to remove this file, show the error and quit, but I was hoping there may be a neater way.. Check the file is available, and then download it ?

Comment: @tobi303 the non trivial thing is that he passes `fp` to libcurl in the setup phase (before the error) and it's libcurl that handles writing in the file. The good way to do it is to create a callback to store the content and to write it in a file later.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use `write_data` write function but a custom one:

```
size_t store_content(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata)
{
    std::string &content = static_cast<std::string>(*userdata);
    content += std::string(ptr, size*nmemb);
    return size*nmemb;
}

void downloadFile(const char* url, const char* fname) {
    CURL *curl;
    FILE *fp;
    CURLcode res;
    std::string content;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl){
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, store_content);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &content);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if (res != 0) {
            fp = fopen(fname, "wb"); // TODO: check errors
            fwrite(content.data(), content.size(), 1, fp); // TODO: check errors 
            fclose(fp);
        }

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
}
```

[`CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEDATA.html) is used to set a function called when data is received by libcurl.
[`CURLOPT_WRITEDATA`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEDATA.html) is used to set a pointer to data you want to be passed to the callback given by `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`